# The artifact poi:poi-2.5-final:jar:20040302 has been relocated to poi:poi:jar:2.5-final-20040302

Tags: maven, warnings, pom.xml

## Problem:

Upon doing a `mvn clean install` of my web app I get only this warning:

```
[WARNING] The artifact poi:poi-2.5-final:jar:20040302 has been relocated to poi:
poi:jar:2.5-final-20040302
```

Inside my `pom.xml` I have `poi` ([Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), for those interested) listed twice :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-2.5-final</artifactId>
    <version>20040302</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>2.5-final-20040302</version>
</dependency>
```

## What I tried (one which worked):

1. I tried commenting out the second one, `2.5-final-20040302`, which is the one the first one is relocated to. But I get the same error.
2. I tried commenting out the first one, `20040302`, and the warning disappears, apparently fixing the problem! :)

## Question:

Can someone explain what happened? Why was there two `poi`'s listed? Was it just a duplication error with different formats? Why did only one format not produce the warning? Etc.

It's hard to ask a question when what I am looking for is basic understanding. For context, the `pom.xml` file was not constructed by me, it was a template Spring/MVC web app project I am basing my code off of. It may or may not have been in error. I am just looking for understanding, although my "hack" fix worked for the moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that artifact was modified at one point so that the format was more maven standard (the 2nd one you list).  So in order to not break backwards compatibility, a redirect was used on the first one.  You have it listed twice, probably because two different developers added it and didn't realize the other was there.  Or it could have been that they knew it was moving and it was used during a transition time or something similar.

The right thing to do is to ditch the first and use the second more proper version.

Comment: Thank you. I stumbled upon the same solution you mention. The only part I don't understand is how a redirect is used. Where or how is that done? Is it automatic or something within the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: If you were to pull that pom (from the first) I believe it would answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean pull it from the first? I'm misreading you.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette This is the pom for the first artifact on repo1.maven.org.  Read it and it'll show you how the redirect works.   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/poi/poi-2.5-final/20040302/poi-2.5-final-20040302.pom

Comment: I see the `<relocation>` tag, but I do not have this tag in my `pom.xml` file above. This is where I am lost. How does the compiler know to redirect? Is the redirect implied when there are duplicate entries?

Comment: When maven is fetching the artifact, it sees that redirect and downloads the "other" pom instead.  That's why you don't see it in your local repo.

Comment: I appreciate your patience with me on this matter! What I don't understand is how Maven sees the redirect. Is this automatic or something I am putting in my `pom.xml` file?

Comment: It's automatic as part of the download artifact logic.  It's something in the repository's pom so it just knows what do to.  You don't have to do anything for it to work.  It's actually mostly used for pre-maven stuff that got added to maven with poor group and artifact ids and later got standardized.  Hope this explains it.

Comment: Thank you, it explains it well. It's just nice to understand why things are happening.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette agreed.  Glad I could help.